# “message”: "Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::$map"

Tags: php, laravel, api

I keep getting this error when trying to show an author data by id
when write `Route::get('authors/{id}'`, `'App\Http\Controllers\Api\UserController@show');` in `api.php` and     Public function show `($id){$user=User::findOrfail($id);Return new UserResource($user);}` this problem show me

**Api.php**

```php
<?php
namespace App\Database\routes\Api;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller;
use App\Http\Controllers\Api;
Route::get('authors/{id}', 'App\Http\Controllers\Api\UserController@show');
```

**UserController.php**

```php
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api;
use App\Http\Resources\UserResource;
use App\Http\Resources\UsersResource;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $users =  \App\Models\User::paginate();
            return new UsersResource( $users);
    }
    public function store(Request $request) { }
    public function show($id)
    {
     //       UserResource(\App\Models\User::find($id) );
             return new UserResource(User::find($id));
    }
}
```

**UserResource.php**

```php
<?php
namespace App\Http\Resources;
use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\ResourceCollection;
use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\Resource;
class UserResource extends ResourceCollection
{
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return parent::toArray($request);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Return your user key and value**

```
return
        [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'name' => $this->name,
            'email' => $this->email,
            'created_at' => $this->created_at,
            'user' => new UserResource($this->user)
        ];
```

Comment: but i don't want to return value of data in show function,do you have another method?

Answer (score 0):

```
        public function index(Request $request)
            {
                $users =  \App\Models\User::paginate();
        
        if( $request->is('api/*')){
                   
                    $users = UserResource::collection($users);
                    return $this->sendResponse(compact( users'));
                }
         
            }
    
    that is user show api

public function show($id ,Request $request)
    {
        $user = User::find($id);
    
     if( $request->is('api/*')){
                $user = new UserResource($user);
                return $this->sendResponse(compact('user'),$message);
            }
}
```

Comment: index  function works without any problem,but show function has a problem

Comment: you can not add request on your method directly return your sendResponse

Comment: your method is good,but it shows me error "the message is not defined" what can i define message variable??

Answer (score 0):

Try using model binding

```
  public function show(User $user)
       {
 
         return new UserResource($user);
      }
```